# Query nested object in Firestore REST API

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm stuck with querying Firestore REST API. I can figure out how to filter by a regular key but I can't figure out how to query by nested object key.

Basically, in the browser client, I can do

```
firestore.collection("channels")
   .where("members.[memberID]", "==", true)
   .get()
```

However, when I try to do the same in the REST API, it said Invalid Argument. I was trying to do

```
{
 "structuredQuery": {
  "where": {
   "fieldFilter": {
    "field": {
     "fieldPath": "members.[memberID]"
    },
    "op": "EQUAL",
    "value": {
       booleanValue: "true"
    }
   }
  },
  "from": [
   {
    "collectionId": "channels"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

but it gives me "Invalid Argument" error on `fieldPath`. Does anybody know how to query Firestore REST API based on nested object?

Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem ... can't find a good answer to it.

Comment: What I may have to do is convert it to a string using JSONModel and then convert it back.  Which seems a bit ugly.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but where do you pass this object with the structured query? I am passing it as request body and it does not work at all. Could someone share a whole example? Would be helpful.

Comment: @GeorgiArnaudov
you need to pass the whole `structuredQuery` object in the request body, what I have above is the request body

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I asked for Firebase support and they said special characters in `fieldPath` such as "-" in my case can be escaped using back tick or back slash. It is mentioned [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents#Document.FIELDS.fields). In my case, I'll need to do

```
members.`[memberID]`
```

I hope this is helpful for you guys.